# How to click on an item in a recycler view?

Tags: regression-testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm building page objects for regression testing and there are a few views that incorporates a recycler view with list items and I have found one solution but I can't get it work. What I get is that "The name index doesn't exist in the current context"

What am I doing wrong here?

My code:

```js
Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> _listItem(int index) => e => e.Marked("text_left_icon_right_list_item_textview").Index(index);

public SomethingPage(IApp app)
{
    _app = app;
}

public void SelectSomething()
{
    _app.Tap(_listItem(index));
}
```

The code of the solution I found: [Page Object Pattern In Xamarin UITest](https://xamarinhelp.com/page-object-pattern-will-make-better-xamarin-ui-automation-tester/).

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong ^^ :P 
I had forgotten to put int index in the parentheses of public void SelectSomething()

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess... but I believe you need to add `int index` as a parameter for the `SelectSomething()` method. :)